# Phonegap / Xcode Updated Splash Screen Images Now Won't Build

Tags: cordova, xcode7, splash-screen

I have Phonegap project for iOS.  I just updated the splashscreen images in 3 different folders by just overwriting them.  When I go to build the app now it fails with the following errors:

**OUTPUT FROM TERMINAL**

Current launch storyboard undefined

Not changing launch storyboard setting in info plist.

Need to update build settings because project is using legacy launch images and no storyboard.

Set ASSETCATALOG_COMPILER_LAUNCHIMAGE_NAME to LaunchImage because project is using legacy launch images and no storyboard.

Error: Error
    at /private/var/root/tester/platforms/ios/cordova/lib/prepare.js:239:29
    at _fulfilled (/private/var/root/tester/platforms/ios/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:834:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (/private/var/root/tester/platforms/ios/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:863:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/private/var/root/tester/platforms/ios/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:796:13)
    at /private/var/root/tester/platforms/ios/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:857:14
    at runSingle (/private/var/root/tester/platforms/ios/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:137:13)
    at flush (/private/var/root/tester/platforms/ios/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:125:13)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:67:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:607:11)

**END OUTPUT FROM TERMINAL**

I didn't change any settings in config.xml or Xcode during this and the app was able to build before overwriting the images.  Didn't think it would be a problem since I was just replacing images.

If anyone wants more details I can provide but figured I must be doing something quite dumb and simple here.

Comment: re-add platform and replace images. don't modify anything else.

Comment: Removing and adding the platform is one the easiest solution for the phonegap/cordova projects's platform specific issue, if that don't solve your issue you can check the steps provided in the answer

Comment: Thank you Hardik and AdiHardik, removing and then re-adding the platform did solve the issue.  I didn't want to do what I thought was a drastic step but in the end that was the right call.  For your help I have marked your answer below as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your older configuration is set to storyboard for the launch screen image, but now in overwriting the folder, it got replaced

Open your Xcode and check Go to General and check the launch screen configuration as shown in the image below:

[image]

Remove the launch screen file entry and click the 'Use Asset Catalog' for launch image source. Generate the required images for the launch screen catalog and your code should run now

After the change is should something like this:

[image]